# Probability of exoplanet transit

Tags: mathematics, transits-other-than-sun

An exoplanet is in a *circular* orbit around its star.

The radius of the star is $r_{star}$

The radius of the exoplanet is $r_{planet}$

The radius of the orbit is $r_{orbit}$.

The orbital period of the planet is $T$

What is the probability that, from the perspective of a distant observer who is viewing the system from a random angle (in 3D, alternatively and equivalently, the orbital plane is randomly oriented), the (full) disk of the exoplanet occludes the disk of its star during an observation duration $t$ (randomly offset)?

Is there an analytic solution for this problem?

Comment: I started to answer but then realised what you are asking is more complex than I first thought... I think there is an analytic solution, though mostly I believe it is Monte-Carlo integrated to take into account observing cadence and signal to noise too.